# Loop through colored checkboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have five different colored checkbox backgrounds on my form and I would like to compress the executable code segment (see below). Is there a way to do it better?

```
private void CheckBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, 0, 13, 13);
    }
}
private void CheckBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox2.Checked)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, 0, 0, 13, 13);
    }
}
private void CheckBox3_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox3.Checked)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, 0, 0, 13, 13);
    }
}
private void CheckBox4_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox4.Checked)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Green, 0, 0, 13, 13);
    }
}
private void CheckBox5_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox5.Checked)
    {
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, 0, 0, 13, 13);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a __common__ paint event for all! (Select all and paste the event name into the event pane's Paint slot !) - Cast `sender` to checkBox to determine which it is and which Color to use. You could also set the Tag of each to the fill color, if it will always be the same..

Comment: I did not remember to use a common paint event... I immediately try it out! Thank you very much "TaW"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, as TaW has commented (and I would have implemented) you can:

- Click on `CheckBox1_Paint` and press Ctrl-R-R, rename it to `AnyCheckBox_Paint`
- Change the code to be:

```
private void AnyCheckBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is CheckBox cb && cb.Checked)
    {
        using(var b = new SolidBrush(Color.FromName(cb.Tag.ToString())))
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, 0, 0, 13, 13);
    }
}
```

- Visit the designer and select all your checkboxes, go to the properties grid lightning bolt (events) and pick `AnyCheckBox_Paint` from the dropdown next to the Paint event line
- Now you just have to put a string name of a color in the Tag property of each checkbox. Alternatively you could color the fore or backcolor the color you want and use that in your code rather than parsing from a string in the tag
- Finally you can remove the Paint event handlers once there are `0 references` written above them (removing an event handler that is still referenced by the designer will cause an error that means you have to edit the form's Designer.cs to get the designer showing again)

You could also look at caching the brushes if you want, rather than using them and disposing them

Comment: Many thanks for your kindly support, Caius : )

Answer (score 2):

You could declare a Dictionary or KeyValuePair for the Checkboxes and the corresponding Colors you want to fill in like so:

```
private Dictionary<CheckBox, Brush> _checkboxColours;
```

Then inside your Constructor populate the Dictionary as seen below:

```
this._checkboxColours = new Dictionary<CheckBox, Brush>
            {
                { this.checkBox1, Brushes.Red },
                { this.checkBox2, Brushes.Green },
                { this.checkBox3, Brushes.Yellow },
                { this.checkBox4, Brushes.Green },
                { this.checkBox5, Brushes.Yellow },
            };
```

Then you can specify the paint method for each of the checkboxes like so:

```
            this.checkBox1.Paint += this.CheckBox_Paint;
            this.checkBox2.Paint += this.CheckBox_Paint;
            this.checkBox3.Paint += this.CheckBox_Paint;
            this.checkBox4.Paint += this.CheckBox_Paint;
            this.checkBox5.Paint += this.CheckBox_Paint;
```

Then you can have 1 paint method for each that uses the Dictionary to find the color to paint and then fill them in like so:

```
private void CheckBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            var checkbox = sender as CheckBox;
            if ((bool)(checkbox?.Checked))
            {
                var parsed = _checkboxColours.TryGetValue(checkbox, out Brush color);
                if (parsed)
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(color, 0, 0, 13, 13);
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, 13, 13);
                }
            }
        }
```

Which when running looks like so:

[image]

Comment: Will update, I'm at work currently typed it all out in the answer box, my bad.

Comment: The solution of one problem is a new problem ; )  The code  snippet is beautiful an clear!  Thank you  very much for your support and help Connor!